# Failover for email images

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I am developing a system that sends emails out to recipients who may read the email from a public access point, or a "closed" access point (that can't see the internet). My emails, which are sent in HTML format, might have images embedded. The images are pre-defined and live in known locations. Naturally, **email read from the (public) internet can't load images hosted in the (private) closed network; email read from the closed network can't load images from the internet**.

For now, during email generation we are determining from the recipient's email address whether we should set the `img src` to be the public or private path. **I'd love to find a native HTML technique that could tell the email client "try this public path to the image, and if it doesn't load failover to this private path".** My understanding is that email clients are almost always expected to strip-out JavaScript, so ECMA won't be a part of this solution. Sadly.

### Attempt 1

I tried setting the `src` to be the public path to the image, and set the `background-image` style attribute to be the private path to the image:

`<img src="path/to/`**`public`**`/my_image.jpg" style="background-image:url('path/to/`**`private`**`/my_image.jpg');" ..etc.. />`

That works great in a browser (especially if height/width attributes are set), but Outlook (2007) does not support `background-image`. So, no joy.

### Attempt 2

I tried creating a `table` with a `background` image:

```
<table background="path/to/private/my_image.jpg">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <img src="path/to/public/my_image.jpg" />
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Outlook didn't go for that either.

### Attempt 3

In the spirit of "it just might be crazy enough to work", I tried supplying two `src` attributes to an image:

`<img src="path/to/`**`public`**`/my_image.jpg" src="path/to/`**`private`**`/my_image.jpg" ..etc.. />`

That didn't work anywhere; only the first `src` would get used to try to load the image.

Comment: Not sure if this will work. Would all need to be inline styles obviously. Set a width, height and position relative on the TD. Add two images inside the TD with position absolute and the correct width and height and different z-indexes and top:0 left:0 values. I've never tried this so it may be a big pile of FAIL but you could give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

If your logic is made on the server, I think you'd be better off linking to a script that generates / serves the correct image, instead of an image directly?

**Something like:**

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/path/to/script/image.php?email=info@example.com&amp;name=example-image-1" />
```

`image.php` would then base some logic on the parameters given. These could be the email of the recipient (which could detail their access rights) and perhaps a name for the image (so that you know which image to serve in this position).

You would then need to serve `image.php` as the correct mime type of an image, so that the email client can render it correctly.

This would be far more advantageous over trying to use hacks in the email itself.

Hope this helps?

Mikey.

PS - Remember to serve absolute URL's in HTML emails. Relative images won't work.

Comment: "email read from the (public) internet can't load images hosted in the (private) closed network; email read from the closed network can't load images from the internet"...this applies to all assets--pages too. So half the people wouldn't be able to get to `http://www.example.com/path/to/script/image.php`.

Comment: Well, for this use case, is it not possible to create generic assets available to both parties? Something that becomes the bridge between the two areas? Without that middle-ground, I'm not sure how you'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not embed the images as attachments? You can specify the src attribute of the img tags as "cid:xyz" where "xyz" if the "Content-id" MIME attribute of the image attachment.

Comment: Good idea, but specifically ruled-out by the customer.